# What do you call making a sound of derision or contempt by blowing through closed lips (but not using the tongue)?

Tags: expressions

In this [clip of the movie 'Moana'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPsnNKDpYlo), at 13 seconds into the video, Moana says "Teach me to sail," to which Maui makes a sound of derision or contempt by blowing through closed lips without using the tongue.

What do you call Maui's act of making this sound?

Is it called "Bronx cheer" or "blowing a raspberry" or something else?

As I understand it, both Bronx cheer and blowing a raspberry would involve the use of the tongue as well as the lips. If so, Maui's act is not exactly Bronx cheer or blowing a raspberry, because he didn't use the tongue at all.

Is there a separate term for making the sound only with the lips? Or can Bronx cheer or blowing raspberry be used to describe the act of making such a sound only with the lips?

Comment: ***Bronx cheer***: a rude sound made by sticking the tongue out and blowing. - ***Blow a raspberry***: - To make a sputtering noise by pressing the tongue and lips together. It can be used to express either real or faux contempt, mockery, or displeasure.

Comment: Note that, whatever sound you produce with your mouth, the tongue always plays a role, possibly a minor one. A whistle of disapproval

Comment: @Josh But note that in the clip Maui doesn't really use his tongue at all.

Comment: Excellent question! The onomatopoetic representation of that sound is _pffft_ (with as few or as many f’s as you want), but I can't think of a descriptive term for it.

Comment: If there was a way to reference the script, you could see how it was represented there.

Comment: @JanusBags Damn! I was about to suggest 'pfft'. Now I can't. You beat me to it :-|. I do think it is the closest.

Answer (score 4):

With permission from @Josh and @JanusBahs maybe, I think we might name the sound '**pfft**'...
 
From [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pfft)
***Pfft:***

> 1. Used to signify a sudden ending or disappearance
> 2. Used to signify sarcasm or disagreement
> 3. (onomatopoeia) Used to signify a puffing sound

This [link](http://m.ranker.com/list/moana-movie-quotes/movie-and-tv-quotes) also describes the sound as 'pfft'. I couldn't find movie quotes elsewhere.

Also without any strong reference of a renowned dictionary I have this defination from [Lingo2Word](http://www.lingo2word.com/lingodetail.php?WrdID=26967).

> :The word pfft is used in Slang [sic] meaning ***the sound created by expelling air through the teeth and lips***,yeah whatever,an expression of dismissal.

Comment: Thanks. How about "mouth fart"? :)

Comment: closely related (but not the same): [pssh](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pssh)

Answer (score 0):

Lip raspberries. Part of baby motor skills.

"When a baby blows a raspberry using the lips only, this helps build up strength. The lips have an important part of a baby learning to drink from a cup and also to eat and chew foods."

[https://www.chicagoparent.com/learn/health-fitness/raspberries-spit-bubbles-just-drooly-fun-good-developing-babies/]